Why is the usage of 真 in 那是个真热闹的地方 considered an error?




This is a question from 国际汉语教师证书 考试真题集 (pp.6-7; digital version here).  I'm interested in why:

……，那是个真热闹的地方，……

is considered incorrect.  But I can't really think of why this is problematic.  I don't think the answer could be A or D because e.g. 真漂亮, 真贵, 真淘气 are fairly common phrases.  I also think 那个地方真热闹 is fine, much like how you might say 那个女人真美丽 or 你个答案真不错.
So there seems to be something wrong precisely with the combination:

真 + [形容词] + 的 + [名词]

but I'm finding it hard to pinpoint the problem.
Question: Why is the usage of 真 in 那是个真热闹的地方 considered an error?

真: real, actual, true, genuine
lively: bustling with activity = busy
In English we say real busy, just as in Chinese 真热闹:
real: adverb: Informal. very or extremely: You did a real nice job painting the house.
Yeah, yeah. I'm normally real busy.
是啊，是的，我平时很忙。
对岸挤满了人，真热闹！
The other bank is full of people, (it's) real busy!
那里到处都彩旗飘扬，人来人往，真热闹啊！
(Over) there is all fluttering coloured flags, people coming and going, (it's) real busy!
端午到，挂香包，吃粽子，家家户户真热闹！
When Dragon Boat Festival comes around, people are hanging up fragrant bags, eating 粽子, every household is real busy
这个城市真热闹。
This city is real busy.
假期到，真热闹。
(When) holiday time arrives it's real busy (here).
So there is nothing wrong with 真热闹 or real instead of really. Spoken language takes precedence over proscriptive grammar.
如果你想要一间让你像小孩子一样去度假的树屋，
If you want a tree-house vacation that will make you feel like a child again,
位于印度喀拉拉(Kerela)会是一个让你长久的梦想成真的地方。
Kerala in India may be just the place to turn your long-held dream into a real place.
So what is wrong with:
那是个真热闹的地方
We don't like this because we are not sure if 真 points at 热闹 or 地方, which makes it ambiguous. You can correct it simply like this:
那真是个热闹的地方
that really is a busy / lively / noisy place

The problem is the placement of 是

真是 = "really" (真 here is an adverb that intensifies the adjective 热闹)

Example:
热闹 = lively
[真]热闹 = [really] lively
[真是]热闹 = [really] lively
[真是][个热闹的地方] = [really is][a lively place]

是真 = "is real" (真 here is an adjective, stating an object is real and not fake)

Example:
[是][真热闹] = [is] [real liveliness]
[是]个[热闹的地方] = [is] a [lively place]
[是]个[真热闹的地方] = [is] a [real lively place]
I think the answer is [A] because of the 是 before it
真 can modify an adjective, but 是真 cannot

Surely answer A is false as a general rule? I'm not too sure about 是真 either, but then there's no 是真 in the question (before 真 is 个, not 是). The question also states that it's the placement of 真, not 是, that's the problem.

Grammar questions aside, I'm also unclear whether you're saying that "[是]个[真热闹的地方] = [is] a [real lively place]" is acceptable for you or not.

I believe the answer's B because 真 is an adverb that frequently pairs with the main verb. In this case, it's best placed before 是, with which it forms a natural collocation.
Using it as an intensifier within a (syntactically) less important attributive phrase is a bit awkward and lopsided, especially as it leaves the main verb (是) absolutely bare in comparison.
My take is that this is more a question of style and less a question of grammar. But to the extent that it is, it feels akin to saying something equally lopsided like "阅读+书", by which I mean: the 'mistake' is explained by the lack of relative balance within the hierarchy of the different parts of speech.

put it this way
1那真是个热闹的地方
2那个地方真热闹
1&2 both say that place is really lively.
but
3那是个真热闹的地方
3 says that lively place is real.
and if there is no dialogue background, a Chinese guy may joke "any fake lively place?"
anyway the sentence itself is not wrong, it just doesn't fit the vibe.

"真" is an adjective (that means "true/real/genuine"), and "真是" is an adverb (that means "really"). With these notes in mind, you can compare the sentences below to see where the error lies.

那(that)是(is)个(a)真(true/real/genuine)热闹的(lively)地方(place).

那(that)真是(really)个(a)热闹的(lively)地方(place).


Note, the first sentence would be fine if "真" is replaced with "很" (very - adv), or "相當" (quite - adv).

真 can be an adjective on its own. Are you suggesting that the examples mentioned by the OP (真漂亮, 真贵, 真淘气, 那个地方真热闹, 那个女人真美丽, 你个答案真不错) are all wrong?

@Sanchuan A praising or derogating phrase (a subjective comment - 主觀性的評語) can be formed by [真 + adj] to emphasize the truthfulness of the comment deemed by the commenter, but it shall be placed at the end of the comment without adjunct or 的 follows. For example: 她真漂亮(correct); 她真漂亮的(wrong); 她是一個真漂亮的女人(wrong). The last example is correct if 真 replaced by 很 (clearly an adverb).

Right. So you agree that 真+Adj is fine as a 谓语, but not as a 定语. Which means you agree that the answer is B?

@Sanchuan What is the difference between "那是个真热闹的地方" and "那是个很热闹的地方 in view of 谓语? Why?

In your example, none: both 真 and 很 are used to qualify a 定语从句 within a 谓语. Whereas in "真是个热闹的地方", 真 is used to qualify a whole 谓语 (ie 是个热闹的地方, which happens to have a 定语 within it). That's why I believe we can argue that 真+Adj when used as part of a whole 谓语 is more generally acceptable than when used as part of a 定语从句. And I understand that's just what answer B in the textbook says.

B  right
“真” usually used in Exclamatory Sentences
“XX真+adj.”    “真+adj.” explains the situation of “xx”
“那个地方真热闹！”
